# Theme.AppCompat.Light get Actionbar returns null in API 11

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-manifest, android-theme

Theme.AppCompat.Light get Actionbar returns null in API 11.

I have the follow code:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:maxSdkVersion="19"
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

     <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
```

Here is the action bar call in activity:

```
int currentVersionOfAPI = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentVersionOfAPI < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_gameaction);
            android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab = this.getSupportActionBar();
            if (ab != null) {
                ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
                ab.setTitle(GD.getName());
            }
        } else {
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_gameaction);
            ActionBar ab = this.getActionBar();
            if (ab != null) {
                ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                ab.setTitle(GD.getName());
            }
```

I am running on Android 3.0 Emulator and the getActionBar() return null.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Android 4.0 up and lower than 3.0 works fine.

Comment: You can just change Activity to ActionBarActivity,then you can use getSupportActionBar on all devices up API 7.

Comment: past you logs here....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an application, it works fine for all devices except the galaxy tabs with Android 3.x, and my app is in the store, so the pressure was a little too much to fix it and this is how I did it :

1.Use a values-v11 with a correct style that shows the title and the action bar.

2.if you are using navigation drawer forget about the `SetHomeButtonEnabled()` method, it doesn't exist on Honeycomb.

3.Use this piece of code before the  `setContentView` of your (ActionBar)Activities :

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11 && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <=13) 
        { 
            getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR); 
        }
```

I'm running the app in a Galaxy Tab 10 with H 3.2 and it's working fine